# Checking for and indexing non-unique/duplicate values in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unique

I have an array `traced_descIDs` containing object IDs and I want to identify which items are not unique in this array. Then, for each unique duplicate (careful) ID, I need to identify which indices of `traced_descIDs` are associated with it.

As an example, if we take the traced_descIDs here, I want the following process to occur:

```
traced_descIDs = [1, 345, 23, 345, 90, 1]
dupIds = [1, 345]
dupInds = [[0,5],[1,3]]
```

I'm currently finding out which objects have more than 1 entry by:

```
mentions = np.array([len(np.argwhere( traced_descIDs == i)) for i in traced_descIDs])
dupMask = (mentions > 1)
```

however, this takes too long as `len( traced_descIDs )` is around 150,000. Is there a faster way to achieve the same result?

Any help greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While dictionaries are O(n), the overhead of Python objects sometimes makes it more convenient to use numpy's functions, which use sorting and are O(n*log n). In your case, the starting point would be:

```
a = [1, 345, 23, 345, 90, 1]
unq, unq_idx, unq_cnt = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
```

If you are using a version of numpy earlier than 1.9, then that last line would have to be:

```
unq, unq_idx = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
unq_cnt = np.bincount(unq_idx)
```

The contents of the three arrays we have created are:

```
>>> unq
array([  1,  23,  90, 345])
>>> unq_idx
array([0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0])
>>> unq_cnt
array([2, 1, 1, 2])
```

To get the repeated items:

```
cnt_mask = unq_cnt > 1
dup_ids = unq[cnt_mask]

>>> dup_ids
array([  1, 345])
```

Getting the indices is a little more involved, but pretty straightforward:

```
cnt_idx, = np.nonzero(cnt_mask)
idx_mask = np.in1d(unq_idx, cnt_idx)
idx_idx, = np.nonzero(idx_mask)
srt_idx = np.argsort(unq_idx[idx_mask])
dup_idx = np.split(idx_idx[srt_idx], np.cumsum(unq_cnt[cnt_mask])[:-1])

>>> dup_idx
[array([0, 5]), array([1, 3])]
```

Comment: I'm much more comfortable with this answer and it doesn't appear to take much longer than the dictionary answer above. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5):

There is [`scipy.stats.itemfreq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.itemfreq.html) which would give the frequency of each item:

```
>>> xs = np.array([1, 345, 23, 345, 90, 1])
>>> ifreq = sp.stats.itemfreq(xs)
>>> ifreq
array([[  1,   2],
       [ 23,   1],
       [ 90,   1],
       [345,   2]])
>>> [(xs == w).nonzero()[0] for w in ifreq[ifreq[:,1] > 1, 0]]
[array([0, 5]), array([1, 3])]
```

Comment: I didn't know about this function. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 3):

Your current approach is `O(N**2)`, use a dictionary to do it in `O(N)`time:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> traced_descIDs = [1, 345, 23, 345, 90, 1]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i, x in enumerate(traced_descIDs):
...     d[x].append(i)
...     
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...     if len(v) == 1:
...         del d[k]
...         
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [0, 5], 345: [1, 3]})
```

And to get the items and indices:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> dupIds, dupInds = izip(*d.iteritems())
>>> dupIds, dupInds
((1, 345), ([0, 5], [1, 3]))
```

Note that if you want to preserver the order of items in `dupIds` then use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method.

Comment: Personally I would prefer the numpy solution, but if you want to go this way, the standard library has you covered: from collections import Counter

Comment: Could you expand on exactly what isn't preserved by not using OrderedDict?

Comment: Note that this solution will create a lot of python objects, hence memory useage will explode; that's why staying within numpy is probably preferable, if you are dealing with large datasets.

Comment: @CarlM The output here could have been `[345, 1]`, as dicts have no order. An `OrderedDict` will make sure the output is `[1, 345]`.`

Answer (score 2):

```
td = np.array(traced_descIDs)
si = np.argsort(td)
td[si][np.append(False, np.diff(td[si]) == 0)]
```

That gives you:

```
array([  1, 345])
```

I haven't figured out the second part quite yet, but maybe this will be inspiration enough for you, or maybe I'll get back to it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution of the same vectorized efficiency as proposed by Jaime is embedded in the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
print(npi.group_by(traced_descIDs, np.arange(len(traced_descIDs))))
```

This gets us most of the way there; but if we also want to filter out singleton groups while avoiding any python loops and staying entirely vectorized, we can go a little lower level, and do:

```
g = npi.group_by(traced_descIDs)
unique = g.unique
idx = g.split_array_as_list(np.arange(len(traced_descIDs)))
duplicates = unique[g.count>1]
idx_duplicates = np.asarray(idx)[g.count>1]
print(duplicates, idx_duplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `np.unqiue` for Ndims

I had a similar problem with an ndArray in which I want to find which rows are duplicated.

```py
x = np.arange(60).reshape(5,4,3)
x[1] = x[0]
```

0 and 1 should be duplicates in axis 0.  I used [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and returned all options.  Then use [Jaime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25266510/10450752)'s method to locate the duplicates.

```
_,i,_,c = np.unique(x,1,1,1,axis=0)
x_dup = x[i[1<c]]
```

I unnecessarily use `return_inverse` for clarity.  Here are the result:

```
>>> print(x_dupilates)
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11]]]
```