# Group duplicates by least steps to preserve the order with best effort

Tags: python, list, sorting, numpy, duplicates

I'm breaking my head on the exact approach of the following problem.
I wrote it down to explain it the best I can.

Let's assume I bake pizza's and offer 10 different pizza's.
I don't have a pizza zero with no calories, my range is 1-10.

I get 10 orders in from customers.

Assumption 1: To save time, it's way more efficient to bake the same orders (duplicates) at the same time.

Assumption 2*: If I need to move an order, the customer shouldn't be moved more then 10 orders down (or up)

*I would like to separate this assumption as question number 2, given that the Hungarian method would likely solve this.

Assumption 3: I need to keep track of the changes I made in case I need to change a single order back.

Let's put the pizza orders in an array (or list, doesn't matter):

```
a = np.array([2, 8, 6, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 7, 5])
```

result i'm looking for:

```
a
array([3, 8, 6, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 7, 5])
```

What happened is that I swapped the first order with sixth.
All other orders are unique, so nothing to do here.
I used a simple operation like:

```
a[0], a[5] = a[5], a[0]
```

The next day I get 50 orders in.

```
b = np.random.random_integers(10, size=(50.))
b
array([ 4, 10,  5,  1,  1, 10,  8,  8, 10,  2,  4,  4,  5,  8,  3,  3,  7,
    6,  2,  9,  5,  9,  6, 10,  9,  9,  4,  7, 10,  3,  2,  1,  4,  2,
    8,  9, 10,  7,  5,  6,  8,  2,  5, 10,  2,  8,  6,  6,  7, 10])
```

The first order, I can swap with the 10th order, but not with the 13th, according to the rules (even though they will be made at the same time).

The 2nd order is more difficult.
If I swap it with the 5th order, orders 4 an 5 lose their already present efficiency.
Same for orders 7 and 8 if I would place the 2nd order here.
I could swap it with order 10, but I already did that in the first swap.

So I guess I need to insert it between orders.
The way I see it, the first 12 orders should look like this:

from:

```
[ 4, 10,  5,  1,  1, 10,  8,  8, 10,  2,  4,  4]
```

to:

```
[ 2, 10,  5,  1,  1, 10,  8,  8, 10,  4,  4,  4]
```

then:

```
[ 2,  5,  1,  1, 10, 10,  8,  8, 10,  4,  4,  4]
```

or

```
[ 2,  5,  1,  1, 10,  8,  8, 10, 10,  4,  4,  4]
```

and last:

```
[ 2,  5,  1,  1, 10, 10, 10,  8,  8,  4,  4,  4]
```

or

```
[ 2,  5,  1,  1,  8,  8, 10, 10, 10,  4,  4,  4]
```

But, talking about the number of operations needed, I could as well move orders 6 and 9 to combine with order 2. (two moves needed, same with above example).
Both are good results, but I would try to match it with the closest pair in the case of pizza nr 10.
In the above I need three moves to get my result.

I tried every sort function I could find.
But I want to do it with the least changes to the original.
Lexicographically sorts don't do what I need.
Grouping duplicates results:

```
[[1, 1], [2], [4, 4, 4], [5], [8, 8], [10, 10, 10]]
```

Does an array sort (or list,dict etc) like this exist?
I think I'm missing something obvious or just complex math.
If this is a known mathematical issue, I would like to read more about it.

If it can be done in numpy, consider this data example based on 12/50 from above (order shouldn't be needed but added it for sorting tests):

```
dtype = [('Customer', 'S10'), ('Pizza', int), ('Order', int)]
values = [('Arthur', 4, 1), ('Lancelot', 10, 2),('Galahad', 5, 3),
    ('Peter A', 1, 4),('Bill', 1, 5),('Peter B', 10, 6),('Brad', 8, 7),
    ('Lorelei', 8, 8),('Brian', 10, 9),('Marissa', 2, 10),
    ('Lois', 4, 11),('Joe', 4, 12)]
a = np.array(values, dtype=dtype)
```

edit2: Seems I can make a good start with this: [Checking for and indexing non-unique/duplicate values in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264798/checking-for-and-indexing-non-unique-duplicate-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: An interesting question.  I doubt you will find a ready-made solution for this problem.  (At the least, it has a parameter, namely the maximum distance you're willing to move an order.)  To approach solving it, my guess is you'd want to define a more general notion of "goodness" of a particular ordering (i.e., how much size-switching goes on).  It may be that it's very difficult to find the absolute best solution, but much easier to find a fairly good solution that is a significant improvement on the original order.

Comment: don't have time for a full answer, but I think this could help you a lot: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html

The trick would be in defining an appropriate cost matrix; give entries more than ten away from the diagonal a high cost, and entries with the same order type a reduced cost.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn, BrenBarn
 I made a few adjustments to my question, as assumption 2 makes things more complicated. The Hungarian method seems to be a good solution for this part.