# How to print only the duplicate elements in python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Is there any inbuilt way to print duplicate elements present in a python list.

I can write program for the same.

All I'm searching for is if there is any inbuilt method or something for the same.

For Ex:

For input  `[4,3,2,4,5,6,4,7,6,8]`

I need op `4,6`

Comment: No. There is no built-in function for that

Comment: You can use a list comprehension `print([i for i in set(a) if a.count(i) > 1])`

Comment: There's a numpy function to find unique elements, which can be used for this purpose. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264798/checking-for-and-indexing-non-unique-duplicate-values-in-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the `Counter` class from [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) that does the trick

```
from collections import Counter


lst = [4,3,2,4,5,6,4,7,6,8]
d =  Counter(lst)  # -> Counter({4: 3, 6: 2, 3: 1, 2: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1})
res = [k for k, v in d.items() if v > 1]
print(res)
# [4, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly related duplicate question: [How do I find the duplicates in a list and create another list with them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/how-do-i-find-the-duplicates-in-a-list-and-create-another-list-with-them)

Simple Answer:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,1]
>>> set([x for x in l if l.count(x) > 1])
set([1, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

with simple built-in function you can do :

```
>>> a=[4,3,2,4,5,6,4,7,6,8]
>>> b=[a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] in a[:i]][1:]
>>> b
[4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo

```
    x = [1,2,3,5,3,2]
    y = []
    for a in x:
        if not a in y:
            y.append(a)
    print(a)
```

So here is how it works.Iterate over every items in `x`.If the current iteration item doesn't exist in `y` append it

Comment: This just prints the last numbers of the array called x.